# How to use Google Pub/Sub with Google Dataflow/Beam using Python?

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-pubsub

I'm new to Pub/Sub and Dataflow/Beam. I have done a task in Spark and Kafka, I want to do the same using Pub/Sub and Dataflow/Beam. From what I understood so far Kafka is similar to Pub/Sub and Spark is similar to Dataflow/Beam.

The task is take a JSON file and write to a Pub/Sub topic. Then using Beam/Dataflow I need to get that data into a PCollection. How will I achieve this?

Comment: The Apache Beam Python SDK does not support reading from Pub/Sub. Reference: [Built-in I/O Transforms](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/io/built-in/).

Comment: [Beam-PubSub](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/python/apache_beam/io/gcp/pubsub.py)
What about this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I solved the above problem. I'm able to continuously read data from a pubsub topic and then do some processing and then write the result to a datastore.

```
with beam.Pipeline(options=options) as p:

    # Read from PubSub into a PCollection.
    lines = p | beam.io.ReadStringsFromPubSub(topic=known_args.input_topic)

    # Group and aggregate each JSON object.
    transformed = (lines
                   | 'Split' >> beam.FlatMap(lambda x: x.split("\n"))
                   | 'jsonParse' >> beam.ParDo(jsonParse())
                   | beam.WindowInto(window.FixedWindows(15,0))
                   | 'Combine' >> beam.CombinePerKey(sum))

    # Create Entity.
    transformed = transformed | 'create entity' >> beam.Map(
      EntityWrapper(config.NAMESPACE, config.KIND, config.ANCESTOR).make_entity)

    # Write to Datastore.
    transformed | 'write to datastore' >> WriteToDatastore(known_args.dataset_id)
```

Comment: which runner do u use? it seems this doesn't work with SparkRunner and FlinkRunner, pls help to look at this question: https://beam.apache.org/documentation/runners/spark/#running-on-dataproc-cluster-yarn-backed a bit if u r still on this domain, many thanks

Answer (score 2):

Pubsub is a streaming source/ sink (it doesn't make sense to read/write to it only once). Dataflow python SDK support for streaming is not yet available.

Documentation: https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/release-notes/release-notes-python.

Once streaming is available, you should be able to do this pretty trivially.

However if you are going from file -> pubsub and then pubsub -> pcollection you should be able to do this with a batch pipeline and drop out the pubsub aspect. You can look at the basic file io for beam.

Comment: If you are interested in python streaming you can email dataflow-python-feedback@google.com for questions on when it will be available.

Comment: This is now supported in Python: https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/data-analytics/dataflow-stream-processing-now-supports-python